# What efforts have been made to create self-documenting variable names in the literature?

Tags: notation, soft-question

Consider the following definition of **directed graph**

> #### Definition of Directed Graph Using an Ordered Pair of Sets
>
> > We define a **directed graph** to be an ordered pair $(V, E)$ such that $V$ is a finite set of integers and $E$ is a subset of $V \times V$. Note that $V \times V$ is the set $\begin{Bmatrix}(v_{1}, v_{2}): v_{1}, v_{2} \in V \end{Bmatrix}$.

There are a lot of variable names which are only one letter long, such as $V$ and $E$. That gets to be overwhelming when people define tuples of objects such the tuple contains more than five items.

---

What the the names of some published researchers who write definitions like this:

> #### Definition of Directed Graph Using Classes and Class Attributes
>
> > We define a **directed graph** to be a class $D = (verts, edges)$ such that $D.verts$ is a finite set of integers and $D.edges$ is a subset of $D.verts \times D.verts$.
> >
> > Note that,  $D.verts \times D.verts$ is the set $\begin{Bmatrix}(v_{1}, v_{2}): v_{1}, v_{2} \in V \end{Bmatrix}$

Comment: I'm pretty sure that *almost no mathematicians* have any desire for this, or would cooperate if some petty tyrant decided to try imposing it. I find the top one more readable and easier to follow, and much easier to write out. Such naming conventions are useful in programming because programs deal with vastly more variable names than even complex mathematics generally requires.

Comment: Note also that your version didn't even change the "tuple" you specifically declaimed (though one change in it should have been made).